# ListView doesn't update when list length changes

Tags: flutter

When I add a Widget to the children property of a ListView, the screen is not updated.  Is this expected behaviour?  Here's an example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ListView Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> myWidgets = [
    Container(width: 100 , height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
    Container(width: 100 , height: 100, color: Colors.green),
    Container(width: 100 , height: 100, color: Colors.yellow),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Rebuilding with list length: ${myWidgets.length}');
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(children: myWidgets,),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            myWidgets.add(Container(width: 100 , height: 100, color: Colors.red));
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your print statement showing when you press the button?

Comment: You should use `listview.builder` for dynamic updates.

Comment: @George yes the print statement is shown

Comment: To me the documentation is not clear about the ListView behaviour, so I've raised this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46922

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the LisView.builder constructor.
Here is a example:

```
...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Rebuilding with list length: ${myWidgets.length}');
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: myWidgets.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return myWidgets[index];
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            myWidgets.add(Container(width: 100 , height: 100, color: Colors.red));
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an `expected` behaviour.

You can try with `List<Widget>.from(myWidgets)` or `ListView.builder(..)`, the list will show added items.

The reason is because flutter update view when `compare the widget tree changed`. But widget of the body in the case `ListView(children: myWidgets,),` have `same object pointer` on `myWidgets`.

`List<Widget>.from(myWidgets)` create a `new` List when `Widget build(BuildContext context)` been called again.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Rebuilding with list length: ${myWidgets.length}');
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(children: List<Widget>.from(myWidgets),),   //<---- update here
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            myWidgets.add(Container(width: 100 , height: 100, color: Colors.red));
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
```

or

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Rebuilding with list length: ${myWidgets.length}');
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(                      // <---- update here
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return myWidgets[index];
        },
        itemCount: myWidgets.length,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            myWidgets
                .add(Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.red));
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
```